# What is the fastest way to check whether a specific UserID exists in the array using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects `gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray` with 2 properties (UserID & UserInfo)

For example:

```
gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray[0].UserID = "111"; 
gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray[0].UserInfo = "AAA-111";
gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray[1].UserID = "222"; 
gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray[1].UserInfo = "BDD-478333";
```

What is the fastest way to check whether a specific UserID exists in the array using Jquery or Javascript because `gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray` has got 8000 records?

Thanks

Comment: from the http://jquery.com/ : "jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library"... if You are using jQuery to iterate through the array, You are actually using a JavaScript

Comment: @PiotrSalaciak Am I using a JavaScript too?!

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask: You aren't sending the array with 8000+ users to every user that uses this page, are you?

Comment: I want to avoid adding duplicates values to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, I believe:

```
function exists(uid) {
    var k = gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray.length;
    uid = uid.toString(); // ensure the arg is a str (this can be omitted)
    while (k--) {
        if (gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray[k].UserID === uid) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is the array sorted by the UserID? If so, it can be improved either further by using a binary search; that would change this from O(n) to O(log n). Your example suggests it is. I found a good implementation of a binary search in JavaScript on the web, [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/01/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search/). Here is the code if the site ever dies:

```
function binarySearch(items, value){

    var startIndex  = 0,
        stopIndex   = items.length - 1,
        middle      = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex)/2);

        while(items[middle] != value && startIndex < stopIndex){

        //adjust search area
        if (value < items[middle]){
            stopIndex = middle - 1;
        } else if (value > items[middle]){
            startIndex = middle + 1;
        }

        //recalculate middle
        middle = Math.floor((stopIndex + startIndex)/2);
    }

    //make sure it's the right value
    return (items[middle] != value) ? -1 : middle;
}
```

Comment: If you have time it'd be good to see the implementation anyway.

Comment: You can do a for(var item in array) rather than taking out the need for k whatsoever. Having k in there would be good for if you wanted to know the exact point it exists though

Comment: @Harold a for in check is slower. A standard forward for loop would be faster then a backwards while loop.

Comment: @Raynos: Not necessarily. It varies by the browser, but I seem to remember IE in particular being speedy with backwards while loops (I can't confirm because I'm not on Windows right now). See this test suite: http://blogs.sun.com/greimer/resource/loop-test.html

Answer (score 1):

```
var match = '222';
var matches = $.grep(myArray, function(el, index) {
   return (el.UserID === match);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fasten the search process by using Binary Search algorithm if the array is sorted (e.g with respect to UserId).

```
function binarySearch(array, userid) {
  var low = 0, high = array.length - 1,
      i, comparison;
  while (low <= high) {
    i = parseInt((low + high) / 2, 10);

    if (array[i].UserId < userid) { low = i + 1; continue; };
    if (array[i].UserId > userid) { high = i - 1; continue; };
    return array[i];
  }
  return null;
};
```

You can find the user of which ID is 12 by using the function:

```
var result = binarySearch(gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray, 12);
```

Comment: Good thinking. I missed the bit about 'fastest' way in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
ExistsInArray(value, array){
    for(var item in array){
        if(item.UserId == value){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `for in` is terrible in performance (for JavaScript). Use the regular looping technique is better.

Answer (score -1):

You can either prototype Array object, like this:

```
Array.prototype.exists = function(value, prop){
    var i = null;
    for (i in this)
        if (this[i][prop] && this[i][prop] == value)
            return true;
    return false;
}

gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray.exists('222', 'UserID');
```

Comment: It' a very bad practice to change the prototype of the built in objects, since you change ALL objects of that type. It´s much better to add the function directly to `gAllMedicalFilesClaimantsArray`. (There is one exception to this "rule": if you add standard functionality that the current javascript engine is missing. But that's what jquery and similar libraries is for)

Comment: @some The real problem is when extending `Object.prototype` because you have to filter out the inherited properties(extensions). As long as you don't use `for in` loops to iterate through an array, which is not recommended since there's no guarantee of the order of the properties.

Comment: @JuanMendes Right. But extending the built in objects like this is like using global variables: It usually works, but there are often better ways to do it. And about adding things to `Object.prototype`: with `Object.defineProperty` it should be possible to add properties that isn't enumerable. Scarry.

Comment: @some To clarify what the real problem is... others may try to extend the same `Array.prototype` method that you created and overwrite your definition with different semantics. A common solution (instead of adding the method to a single array, which is not very reusable) is to create a method that you pass the array into, like `ArrayHelper.exists = function (array, prop){...}` and you'd replace the instances of this with array in the function body.

Comment: -1 for using `for (var i in this)` It won't cause a problem in this case, but you shouldn't propagate a pattern that is error prone. The problem is that order of keys isn't guaranteed